# Julia: Can I update and store the same array within an iteration of a for-loop?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, matrix, indexing, julia

I am trying to update an array with a for-loop and store the "current" version of the array within the same iteration of the loop as follows:

```
struct store
    a::Float64
    mat::AbstractArray
end

function foo(x::AbstractArray)
    m, n  = size(x)
    col = Array{store}(undef, m, n)
    A = zeros(m, n)

    for i in eachindex(col)
        A[i] = 1.0
        print(A)
        col[i] = store(x[i], A)
        A[i] = 0
    end

    return col
end
```

I added a print() to check if the array is updated in the way I want it (it is). The matrix I want to store has all zeros except for a "1" at the current position of the index. The result I get is:

```
foo(rand(2,2))

2×2 Array{store,2}:
store(0.447322, [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0])  store(0.949405, [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0])
store(0.56251, [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0])   store(0.156834, [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0])
```

It is possible to achieve what I want by placing the array "A" in the loop, but it is also very inefficient.

Is there better to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you care about efficiency, you should avoid abstract field types in your struct definition. If you want to allow several kinds of arrays, use a parametric struct. (One more piece of advice: use CapitalCase for type names, not lowercase.)

Answer (score 3):

The arrays you describe, with a single index storing a special value, can be represented efficiently using `SparseArrays`.

Because they follow a consistent pattern, the matrices can be generated on the fly. You can avoid storing all of them in memory at once.

This is a memory efficient solution:

```
julia> using SparseArrays

julia> struct Store{N}
           A::Array{Float64,N}
       end

julia> function Base.getindex(store::Store, I...)
           B = spzeros(size(store.A)...)
           B[I...] = 1.0
           return store.A[I...], B
       end
```

Which you can use like this:

```
julia> foo = rand(2,2)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.741406  0.0833667
 0.688376  0.706395

julia> store = Store(foo)
Store{2}([0.7414058497508282 0.08336674477744199; 0.6883759175546191 0.706394665153228])

julia> store[1]
(0.7414058497508282, 
  [1, 1]  =  1.0)
```

The printing for SparseArrays might look strange if you have not used them before, but you can confirm that they behave as expected:

```
julia> a, b = store[4]
(0.706394665153228, 
  [2, 2]  =  1.0)

julia> b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4] # only the fourth index will have a nonzero value
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

As you might have guessed, your problem is due to the fact that the array you insert into `col` is always the same: modifying the array at one iteration modifies it everywhere.

A first way to do what you want would be to `copy` the array when inserting it into `col`:

```
function foo1(x::AbstractArray)
    m, n  = size(x)
    col = Array{store}(undef, m, n)
    A = zeros(m, n)

    for i in eachindex(col)
        A[i] = 1.0
        col[i] = store(x[i], copy(A))
        A[i] = 0
    end

    return col
end
```

Another way would be, as you suggest, to create a new `A` array at each iteration:

```
function foo2(x::AbstractArray)
    m, n  = size(x)
    col = Array{store}(undef, m, n)

    for i in eachindex(col)
        A = zeros(m, n)
        A[i] = 1.0
        col[i] = store(x[i], A)
    end

    return col
end
```

It looks like the second way is a bit more efficient:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> x = rand(2,2)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.899445  0.459424
 0.287892  0.669846

julia> @btime foo1($x)
  241.078 ns (10 allocations: 800 bytes)
2×2 Array{store,2}:
 store(0.899445, [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0])  store(0.459424, [0.0 1.0; 0.0 0.0])
 store(0.287892, [0.0 0.0; 1.0 0.0])  store(0.669846, [0.0 0.0; 0.0 1.0])

julia> @btime foo2($x)
  198.404 ns (9 allocations: 688 bytes)
2×2 Array{store,2}:
 store(0.899445, [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0])  store(0.459424, [0.0 1.0; 0.0 0.0])
 store(0.287892, [0.0 0.0; 1.0 0.0])  store(0.669846, [0.0 0.0; 0.0 1.0])
```

As said in another answer, it would be more efficient to store `A` as a `SparseArray`, especially if it is of large size:

```
using SparseArrays
function foo3(x::AbstractArray)
    m, n  = size(x)
    col = Array{store}(undef, m, n)

    for i in eachindex(col)
        A = spzeros(m, n)
        A[i] = 1.0
        col[i] = store(x[i], A)
    end

    return col
end
```

This strategy does not pay off for such small sizes, but should be the most efficient if your real problem is larger:

```
julia> @btime foo3($x)
  829.851 ns (33 allocations: 1.92 KiB)
2×2 Array{store,2}:
 store(0.899445, [1, 1]  =  1.0)  store(0.459424, [1, 2]  =  1.0)
 store(0.287892, [2, 1]  =  1.0)  store(0.669846, [2, 2]  =  1.0)
```